# Thread is not running in the order

Tags: wpf, multithreading, task

When i change the order of the methods works.
For example

Im using this code:

```
private void RefreshInfo()
    {
        try
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                DXSplashScreen.Show<SplashScreenView1>();
                LoadGrid();
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
            }).ContinueWith(t => DXSplashScreen.Close(),TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

when i run it the splash screen is close fast and do not wait the 5 secons.

But if i run this:

```
 try
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                DXSplashScreen.Show<SplashScreenView1>();
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
                LoadGrid();
            }).ContinueWith(t => DXSplashScreen.Close(),TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

The splash screen waits the 5 seconds.
why?
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't provided enough information for anyone to be able to reproduce your issue but your code looks a bit strange.

First, you should display and close the splash screen on the UI thread.

Second, your `try`/`catch` won't catch any exception that occurs in the task.

Try this:

```
private void RefreshInfo()
{
    DXSplashScreen.Show<SplashScreenView1>();
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        LoadGrid();
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }).ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        DXSplashScreen.Close();
        if (t.Exception != null)
            MessageBox.Show(t.Exception.Message);
    }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}
```

Comment: hello mm8, i will try using this code and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help
This works for me

```
DXSplashScreen.Show<SplashScreenView1>();
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            LoadData();               
        }).ContinueWith(t => {
            grdLicenses.ItemsSource = DataToTable();
            DXSplashScreen.Close();
            if (t.Exception !=null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(t.Exception.Message);
            }},TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

As you said the try was not getting anyerror, there was an error in code becasuse the loadGrid property modifies a control in the main thread.
I moved the loadData that gets the values from the database and then added in the continue the only method that updates the main thread.
Regards